# Double click in empty area of CListBox does not call my double click function

Tags: user-interface, mfc

I am using Visual Studio MFC for GUI programming.

I currently have a CListBox, and I want it to call a function when I double click on an empty part of it. (when no item is selected) Currently, I am only able to add items to it by pressing a separate button.

I made the following test code to test whether the CListBox is responding to a double click at an empty spot.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CScnBuildDlg, CDialog)
    ON_LBN_DBLCLK(IDC_EVENT_LIST, OnDblclkEventList)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CScnBuildDlg::OnDblclkEventList() 
{
    exit(-1); //Currently, it only exits when double clicking on a specific item, not on an empty space
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why double click event detecting on empty area of listBox in mfc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965423/why-double-click-event-detecting-on-empty-area-of-listbox-in-mfc)

Answer (score 0):

An additional way of trapping this event is possible by using [CWnd::Oncommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t3ddsb9.aspx).  If you add this event handler to your dialog code as follows, you will be able to trap the double-click.

```
BOOL CScnBuildDlg::OnCommand(
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
    )
    {
    if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDC_EVENT_LIST && HIWORD(wParam) == LBN_DBLCLK)
        DoSomething ();
    return CDialog::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
    }
```

However, you'll need to be careful because this event will trap the double-click on an existing list box item as well.  You'll also need to make sure that you allow the base class a chance to handle the WM_COMMAND message.  If not, you may experience some strange bugs.